# IntelliJ: Refactoring causes whole file reformat

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, code-formatting

When I perform a refactoring (extract variable for instance) in a .mxml file, IntelliJ reformats the contents whole `<mx:Script>` element. We don't want it to do that because it makes the commits noisier than it needs to be. This in turn complicates merges.

Part of the problem is that we're transitioning from Eclipse to IntelliJ - which has generally been a big improvement - and we're still getting our code style sorted out. So there are some inconsistencies in the format actually present in a particular file. A problem, which to some degree pre-dates our migration. We are working on getting a standard format published, which will help. But we don't need the merge conflicts. This is out of character for IntelliJ. How do we prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, you can track it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64985.

It may help if you change your code style to be similar between Eclipse and IDEA so that reformat doesn't change it.